# Using a database in a Django view

Tags: python, django, django-database

I am wondering how I can update and access django database information while I am inside of a view.

For example, if I was given an HttpRequest inside a view that passed a username and password parameter, and I had already set up a User model with a database in my 'framework' project, how would I go about checking my 'framework_users' database for that username and password?

Thank you in advance for any help you might give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django you access database via models.

First you configure your database access and credentials in `settings.py`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

Then you can perform queries against your models:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

E.g.

```
User.objects.get(username=request.POST["username"])
```

Then there is a special case for safe user authentication for which Django has its own procedure:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests

Comment: Thank you for the help! Oddly enough I *just* found out about this feature right before I saw that you posted it. But thank you for the post none the less!

On the Django safe user authentication, I am not going to use this because my application is based upon receiving Http Requests, performing tasks based on those requests, and it will only do these tasks if a valid username and password is passed. But thank you for the advice.

Comment: You still should use `authenticate()` to check if the password is valid. It provides some forward-compatibility for different password encryption and such. Do not do manual database look ups or try to verify the password yourself if possible.